# Hooking up Polly Policy

Tags: c#, api, polly

Can someone advice why my Policy handle is not handling my WebException error when I know for a fact that the code hit a WebException for a 429 problem? I've been researching this for a while now and need some help.

This is my Polly Policy:

> ```
> return Policy.Handle<WebException>()
>             .WaitAndRetry(15, // We can also do this with WaitAndRetryForever... but chose WaitAndRetry this time.
>             attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1 * Math.Pow(2, attempt)), // Back off!  2, 4, 8, 16 etc times 1/4-second
>             (exception, calculatedWaitDuration) =>  // Capture some info for logging! if needed
>             {
>                 // This is your new exception handler! 
>                 Debug.WriteLine("Retry count: " + retries++);
>                 Debug.WriteLine("Wait Duration: " + calculatedWaitDuration);
>             });
> ```

I'm using it like this:

```
 webResponseWaitRetryPolicy.Execute(() =>
        {
            // Make a request and get a response
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(options.BaseUrl);
                builder.Port = -1;
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
                /// handle parameters
                query["client_key"] = options.ClientKey;
                query["model_id"] = model;
                query["image_url"] = imageUrl;

                builder.Query = query.ToString();
                string url = builder.ToString();
                string content = string.Empty;

                Result objResult;
               HttpWebResponse response = null;


                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                try
                {
                   response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }

                        objResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(content);


                }
                catch(WebException ex)
                {
                    eventualFailures++; 
                    Debug.WriteLine("Failure: " + eventualFailures);


                }
            });

        return objResult;
    }
```

When I run the code, I can see that it trigger the WebException but the Policy is not being called. Please help.

Comment: You are catching the exception in your actions try/catch clause, when doing `Debug.WriteLine("Web Exception")`, hence not enabling Polly to handle the exception. Either throw from your catch clause or better yet do your logging in your policy and remove the try/catch.

Comment: Tried that but didn't have any success. I can see the error being throw in the output but Polly won't pick up the WebException and retry.

Comment: Re "Tried that but didn't have any success", please post the code you used to try that. We need to see the next iteration of non-working code to be able to advise further.

Comment: If debugging the code in Visual Studio, be sure you are not just seeing Visual Studio highlight the exception _before_ Polly gets a chance to handle it, and thinking that means Polly hasn't handled/won't handle the exception. See https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Debugging-with-Polly-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: I put my code up.

Answer (score 1):

Your `try {} catch {}` is swallowing the thrown exceptions before the Polly policy has the chance to handle them.  Where you have:

```
try
{
    /* snip */
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    eventualFailures++; 
    Debug.WriteLine("Failure: " + eventualFailures);
}
```

Use:

```
try
{
    /* snip */
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    eventualFailures++; 
    Debug.WriteLine("Failure: " + eventualFailures);
    throw;
}
```

Explanation: When a `catch` clause catches an exception and does not rethrow it, the exception is not propagated outside the `catch` block when the `catch` block completes. The `catch` block swallows the exception.

For Polly to handle an exception, the exception needs to be propagated out of the delegate you pass to `policy.Execute(() => )`, so that it is thrown back on to the policy, which then handles it.

---

EDIT: The above answer intentionally demonstrates the minimum that needs to be changed from the posted code, to make the Polly policy handle the exception.  As Cyrus suggested in the comments, if the sole use of the `try`/`catch` is for some extra logging, you can instead do that in the `onRetry` clause of the Polly policy, and remove the `try`/`catch` altogether.

---

SECOND EDIT: If the concern is that the Polly policy still eventually rethrows the `WebException` if all retries fail: [this is intentional](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#how-polly-retry-works); RetryPolicy signals that all retries have been made without success by rethrowing the final exception.

If you wish to trap that final exception without having to add your own further `try`/`catch`, Polly [`.ExecuteAndCapture(...)`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md#post-execution-capturing-the-result-or-any-final-exception) can be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the help guys.  The problem was that the WebException is a 429 error. If I don't put the try catch methods in there, my code will blow up.  So what I end up doing is extend the policy a bit more to look like this.

```
>    public static Policy<HttpWebResponse> Get429WebResponseWaitRetryPolicy()
        {
            //Retries policy
            return Policy.Handle<WebException>().OrResult<HttpWebResponse>(r => r == null)
                .WaitAndRetry(15, // We can also do this with WaitAndRetryForever... but chose WaitAndRetry this time.
                attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1 * Math.Pow(2, attempt)), // Back off!  2, 4, 8, 16 etc times 1/4-second
                (exception, calculatedWaitDuration) =>  // Capture some info for logging! if needed
                {
                    // This is your new exception handler! 
                    Debug.WriteLine("Retry count: " + retries++);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Wait Duration: " + calculatedWaitDuration);
                });
        }
```

Then I return the response from the API WebRequest and Polly policy is now able to consume the error thrown and retry.  Which look something like this at the end.

> ```
> Debug.WriteLine("Success: " + eventualSuccesses);
>                     return response;
>                 }
>                 catch(WebException ex)
>                 {
>                     eventualFailures++; 
>                     Debug.WriteLine("Failure: " + eventualFailures);
>                     return response;
>                  }
> ```

Comment: _If_ the system returning the 429 error includes a header indicating how long to wait before retrying, you can use specific Polly policies which handle this: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait . Policies can be constructed to wait for precisely the time the 429 specifies, before retrying. (It sounds in this question as if the `WebException` may not provide that info, but I am leaving the comment here for other users who may experience 429s and wonder how to handle them with Polly.)

Comment: Does "my code will blow up" mean that a `WebException` is still eventually thrown if all retries fail? This is intentional in Polly. If all retries are exhausted without success, Polly will intentionally rethrow the final exception (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#how-polly-retry-works), to signal that overall failure. If you wish to trap that final exception without having to add your own further `try`/`catch`, you can also use Polly `.ExecuteAndCapture(...)`: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md#post-execution-capturing-the-result-or-any-final-exception

Comment: @mountain - Yes, I did look in the header to get the retry info but it was blank Initially, I was planning to use that time as my exponential backoff.  No, it blows up as soon as it encounters the first 429 WebException. It seems like 429 errors behave differently from your normally HttpStatusCode errors.